# What means blocking for boost::asio::write?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm using `boost::asio::write()` to write data from a buffer to a com-Port. It's a serial port with a baud rate 115200 which means (as far as my understanding goes) that I can write effectively 11520 byte/s or 11,52KB/s data to the socket.

Now I'm having a quite big chunk of data (10015 bytes) which i want to write. I think that this should take little less than a second to really write on the port. But `boost::asio::write()` returns already 300 microseconds after the call with the transferred bytes 10015. I think this is impossible with that baud rate?

So my question is what is it actually doing? Really writing it to the port, or just some other kind of buffer maybe, which later writes it to the port.

I'd like the `write()` to only return after all the bytes have **really** been written to the port.

EDIT with code example:

The problem is that i always run into the timeout for the future/promise because it takes alone more than 100ms to send the message, but I think the timer should only start after the last byte is sent. Because `write()` is supposed to block?

```
void serial::write(std::vector<uint8_t> message) {
  //create new promise for the request
  promise = new boost::promise<deque<uint8_t>>;
  boost::unique_future<deque<uint8_t>> future = promise->get_future();
  // --- Write message to serial port --- //
  boost::asio::write(serial_,boost::asio::buffer(message));
  //wait for data or timeout
  if (future.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(100))==boost::future_status::timeout) {
    cout << "ACK timeout!" << endl;
    //delete pointer and set it to 0
    delete promise;
    promise=nullptr;
  }
  //delete pointer and set it to 0 after getting a message
  delete promise;
  promise=nullptr;
}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is baud rate really the same as bit rate?

Comment: 1 [Baud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud) is one symbol per second. If your port uses symbols which encore more than 1 bit, the bitrate can actually go above the baudrate.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know exactly. But I don't think that I can write 10k of data in 300 microseconds.

Comment: How can I know how much bit are encoded in one symbol? The port has a configuration of char_size 8 and one stop bit.

Comment: check this out: http://www.calculator.org/property.aspx?name=data+rate.  You are transfering at about 14KB/s

Comment: Ok, thanks that would mean its 14.0625 kb/s!
But why the `write()` returns after 300! micrcoseconds with 10kb of data?

Comment: Did you check for errors? Also I'd assume you use `boost::asio::serial_port` as the stream argument. Perhaps you could an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Does the data actually transfer in this time or could it be internally buffered and transmitted after the call returns?

Comment: That is my question exactly! I don't know if the data is really transferred, or only buffered somewhere else.

Comment: Have a look at the version(s) of write(...) that use a completion condition for example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload3.html  for the full list see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html

Comment: I also tried the `boost::asio::transfer_all()` condition. Without any change in behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, [`boost::asio::write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html) blocks until all data has been *written* to the stream; it does not block until all data has been *transmitted*.  To wait until data has been *transmitted*, consider using [`tcdrain()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tcdrain.html).

Each serial port has both a receive and transmit buffer within kernel space.  This allows the kernel to buffer *received* data if a process cannot immediately *read* it from the serial port, and allows data *written* to a serial port to be buffered if the device cannot immediately *transmit* it.  To block until the data has been transmitted, one could use `tcdrain(serial_.native_handle())`.

These kernel buffers allow for the write and read rates to exceed that of the transmit and receive rates.  However, while the application may write data at a faster rate than the serial port can transmit, the kernel will transmit at the appropriate rates.